# How to write a function "triplets" that takes in a number and returns a list of triplets?

Tags: python, list, triplet

Write a function triplets that takes a number n as argument and returns a list of triplets such that sum of first two elements of the triplet equals the third element using numbers below n. Please note that (a, b, c) and (b, a, c) represent same triplet.

triplets(5)

[(1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 4), (2, 2, 4)]

Comment: Any code to show us what you tried so far?

Comment: This is a copy pasted homework task. What have you tried so far, where do you stuck? See [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a list comprehension:

```
def triplets(n): 
    return [ (a,c-a,c) for c in range(2,n) for a in range(1,c//2+1) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
def write_triplets(n):
    to_return = []

    if n >= 2:
        for i in range(2, n):
            for j in range(1, i/2+1):
                triplet = (j, i-j, i)
                to_return.append(triplet)

    return to_return


write_triplets(5)
```

OUTPUT:

```
# Result: [(1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 4), (2, 2, 4)] #
```